# What's the behavior of overlaping Image Barriers?

Tags: vulkan

Standard usage of Barriers is relatively straightforward, but I was wondering what is the behavior of two (or more) overlapping Image Barriers (especially with respect to their side effect -- the layout transition). E.g. (pseudocode):

```
begin( commandBuffer );
1: write( image );
2: imageBarrier(
     image,
     src=STAGE_FRAGMENT(from the write at 1:),
     dst=STAGE_FRAGMENT(intended for read in FS of read at 4:),
     appropriate src and dst access flags,
     newLayout=A
   );
3: imageBarrier(
     image,
     src=STAGE_FRAGMENT(from the write at 1:),
     dst=STAGE_TRANSFER(intended for read by transfer of readT at 5:),
     appropriate src and dst access flags,
     newLayout=B
   );
4: read( image ); // through vkCmdDraw -- expects layout A
5: readT( image ); // different kind of read through Transfer -- expects layout B
end( commandBuffer );
```

1. Is this even legal? (can you back it up by spec quote?)
2. What is the image layout at each point of the program?
3. For completeness, what is the proper/best way to write this (one producer, two consumers situation)? (Swap lines 3: and 4: and make it Read-Read dependency?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image cannot assume multiple layouts simultaneously. In the case of the code you suggested above, since the two barriers have no dependencies on each other, one would happen before the other, but the order is not specified. So the layout of the image afterwards would be one or the other. Which means one of the two reading operations is going to fail.

If you have two operations that use the image from two different layouts, then one of those operations must execute before the other, since they both cannot read the image in the layout they need to. And therefore, there must be an execution dependency *between* them:

```
1: write( image );
2: imageBarrier( image, src=COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUT, dst=FRAGMENT_SHADER, newLayout=A );
3: read( image ); // e.g. through vkCmdDraw -- expects layout A
4: imageBarrier( image, src=FRAGMENT_SHADER, dst=TRANSFER, newLayout=B );
5: readT( image ); // different kind of read e.g. Transfer -- expects layout B
```

The dependency in #4 says that the layout transition and later TRANSFER commands will not occur until all previous FRAGMENT_SHADER operations have completed.

> make it Read-Read dependency

It's not a "Read-Read dependency". A layout transition *modifies* the image (theoretically at any rate), just as surely as if you had written values to the image directly. So logically what you have is "I need to read from it in the FS. After that, I have to transition it to a new layout. After that, I need to read from it in a transfer operation".

It's a "Read-Write-Read dependency." The middle part needs to wait until the first read is done, but the second read can't happen until the middle part is finished. You need an execution dependency with an associated image memory barrier&layout transition.

Comment: Ok, that was my intuition(it's apps responsibility -- as always). I was just wondering if I do have to commit to a particular order of the two read functions. (There is some trick for that with subpasses, but not inline then, I guess).

Comment: @krOoze: You can't have two independent subpasses reading from the same image with different layouts either. One *must* be dependent on the other, since the implementation is permitted to interleave subpasses if one is not dependent on the other.

Comment: I meant this(spec quote): "If two subpasses use the same attachment in different layouts but both uses are read-only [...], the application does not need to express a dependency between the two subpasses. [...]"

Comment: @krOoze: Fair enough, though that only applies to attachments, who's memory characteristics are already odd.

Comment: Note that you should avoid dependencies between read-only operations like these by instead specifying both FRAGMENT_SHADER and TRANSFER bits in the dstStageMask of the first image barrier. Then the second image barrier can be removed, generally improving performance..

Comment: @Quinchilion: You can't do that because of the differing layouts of the read operations.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, you're right. That brings the question of whether using a general layout here is worth getting rid of the second barrier. It definitely should be a win on Nvidia hardware at least, considering they ignore image layouts altogether. Hooray for hardware dependent code!

Comment: @krOoze: Actually, Quinchilion pointed me to an interesting issue. The second read operation in your hypothetical is a transfer operation. So... what kind of transfer operation can be used in a *render pass instance*? Because all of the transfer commands can only happen outside of an RPI. And resolve subpasses use the `LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` layout. So I'm wondering *how* you can perform a transfer from an attachment.

Comment: Well, you can end renderpass before the read. Though not as illustrative that way. I just needed any read op with different layout (or at least stage) for the example.

Comment: BTW I was told the barriers have dependency between themselves if written this way (dst stage=src of the next barrier), so it's beggining to be bit of a rabitt hole for me to understand reliably. Just wanted to interpolate 2 things from this Q: 1) If overlapping barriers of the same resource are always evil (which could make for a relatively easy layer chack). 2) If I can easily fork to two reads of different layout (which could mean better performance if the layouts are same in the driver or even if not it could choose whichever path first, making good place to hide latency)

Comment: @krOoze: "*Well, you can end renderpass before the read.*" Then your renderpass's `finalLayout` should be what the next operation expects. So there's no need for a subpass dependency on that.